# The method getParcelableArrayList(String) is undefined for the type MainActivity

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to pass data from the `onReceive()` in my BroadcastReceiverListener class to the `onNewIntent()` emthod in the MainActivity by using of Parcelable interface. How can I get that to work? And how can I get  the data in the `onNewIntent()`?

I appreciate any help.

BroadcastReceiverListener class:

```js
public class BroadcastReceiverListener extends BroadcastReceiver implements
  Parcelable {

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  if (intent.getAction().equals(
    android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {

   WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
     .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
   final List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
   if (results != null) {
    ArrayList<ScanResult> updatedResults = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
     String ssid = results.get(i).SSID;
     if (ssid.startsWith("KD")) {
      updatedResults.add(results.get(i));
     }
    }

    Intent updateIntenet = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    updateIntenet.putParcelableArrayListExtra("broadcast_event",
      updatedResults);
    context.startActivity(updateIntenet);

   }

  }

 }

 @Override
 public int describeContents() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return 0;
 }

 @Override
 public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

}
```

This method is in the MainActiity:

```js
 @Override
     protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
         String intentResult = intent.getStringExtra("broadcast_event");
         if (intentResult != null) {
             List<ScanResult> results = getParcelableArrayList(intentResult);
             String a = deliverBestAccessPoint(results);
             textWifi.setText(a.toString());
         } else {
             textWifi.setText("No route is available.");
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call getParcelableArrayListExtra on the intent you receive:

```
List<ScanResult> results = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("broadcast_event");
```